# prime faces dialog doesn't show content

Tags: primefaces

I'm new to Primefaces. I am using dialog in my programme. The dialog doesn't show content when dialog appears ,it render after long time. Why is that ?

My code is follows.

```
 <p:dialog header="Call Details" widgetVar="dlg_callD" resizable="false" 
                  style="font-family: Cambria, serif;font-size: 13px;line-height: 1.3em;"> 


            <p:selectOneRadio id="options" 
                              style="font-family: Cambria, serif;font-size: 13px;line-height: 1.3em;" 
                              value="#{customerDetailsController.callSuccess}" >  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="YES" itemValue="1" />  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="NO" itemValue="0" /> 

            </p:selectOneRadio>




        </p:dialog>  
   <p:dataTable id="dataTable_POST" var="newConnection" value="#{customerDetailsController.connectionList_voice}"
                     paginator="true" rows="10"  
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                     rendered="#{customerDetailsController.render_mobileList}">

            <p:column headerText="Call Count"
                      style="font-family: Cambria, serif;font-size: 13px;line-height: 1.3em;width:24%;">  
                <h:outputText value="#{newConnection.call_count}" 
                              style="font-family: Cambria, serif;font-size: 13px;line-height: 1.3em;" />  
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="width:4%">  

                <p:commandButton id="selectButton" value="View"  title="View"  onclick="dlg_callD.show()" actionListener="callAtempController."
                                 style="font-family: Cambria, serif;font-size: 13px;line-height: 1.3em;" >
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{newConnection.mobile_no}" target="#{customerDetailsController.selectedMobileNo}" /> 
                </p:commandButton>

            </p:column>  

        </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your    tag there will something and that will be after start  use  or  tag.

```
 <p:dialog>
     <h:panelGrid>
         Your Dialog content......
     </h:panelGrid>
  </p:dialog>
```

I Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

You actioneListner in the commandButton selectButton is "actionListener="callAtempController.""  --> Wrong value.

Comment: I remove that "actionListener="callAtempController."" but it doesn't work yet. it's take long time to render the content .